# Binary sequences and ${2}^{\mathbb{N}}$ have the same cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, cardinals

I recently got the book "selected problems in real analysis", and I'm stuck solving the very first problem

$(u_n)$ is a binary sequence iff it only contains $0$ and $1$ in the sequence

Let $A$ be the set of all binary sequences

I have to prove that $A$ and ${2}^{\mathbb{N}}$ have the same cardinality, that is to say there exists a 1-1 function from one set to another

I've thought about maybe considering integers as base-2 numbers

Thanks for your help

Comment: This has nothing to do with base two numbers. Imagine you are given a subset $S$ of $\mathbb N$. What 0-1 sequence (i.e. map $\mathbb N\to\{0,1\}$) can you define by making use of $S$ in the most natural way?

Comment: $0$ if n is even, $1$ if n is odd ?

Comment: @Gabriel: That has nothing in particular to do with $S$, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: By $2^{\Bbb N}$ I presume you mean the power set of $\Bbb N$, rather than the set of functions $\Bbb N\to\mathbf{2},$ where $\mathbf{2}:=\{0,1\}$, as these are precisely the binary sequences, and there's nothing to prove. Have you heard of [indicator functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)?

Comment: thanks, the function that to a subset $S$ associates the indicator of every integer toward $S$ should do.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that will indeed be a bijection from $2^{\Bbb N}$ to the set of functions $\Bbb N\to\mathbf{2}.$

Comment: I meant the function that to a subset S associates the sequence of the values of the indicator of every integer toward S

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the indicator of every integer toward $S$." For any $S\subseteq\Bbb N$, the indicator function of $S$ is the function $\mathbf{1}_S:\Bbb N\to\{0,1\},$ given by $$\mathbf{1}_S(n)=\begin{cases}0 & n\notin S\\1 & n\in S.\end{cases}$$ that is, $\langle\mathbf{1}_S(n)\rangle_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is *a binary sequence* for each $S\in2^{\Bbb N}$. Your job is to show that the map $S\mapsto\langle\mathbf{1}_S(n)\rangle_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a bijection from $2^{\Bbb N}$ to the set of binary sequences.

Comment: Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb {N}$

Let $f:P(\mathbb {N}) \rightarrow A$ where $A$ is set of all binary sequences
such that: 

$\forall i\in \mathbb {N},  (f(S)_i=0$ if $i\in S$ or$ f(S)_i=1$ if $i\notin S$)

Comment: That will also work as a bijection.